# How to update my ListView after deleting the list item from another Activity?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I got problem in delete function there.When I click on delete, it works and delete the record in sqlite. But the problem is after it delete, it jump back to previous activity that using listview. But the deleted records still appear at there. I need to go out from the listview activity and go back again it just disappear.
How should I do?

Here my delete function in database

```
public Integer deleteData (String property)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return db.delete(houseContract.houseEntry.table2_name,"Property = ?",new String[] {property});
}
```

Here is my delete button works at the activity

```
public class SellerHouseDetail extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText etAddress,etDetail,etShowID;
TextView txType,txProperty,txPrice,txState,txTitle,txOther,txSize,txFullname;
Button bDelete;
String type,property,price,state,address,title,other,size,detail,fullname;
HousesDB db = new HousesDB(this);
Houses houses;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seller_house_detail);

    txType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txTypes);
    txProperty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txProperty);
    txPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txPrice);
    txState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txState);
    etAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
    txTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txTitle);
    txOther = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txOther);
    txSize = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txSize);
    txFullname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txFullname);
    etDetail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDetail);
    etShowID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etShowID);
    bDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDelete);

    fullname = txFullname.getText().toString();
    type = txType.getText().toString();
    property = txProperty.getText().toString();
    price = txPrice.getText().toString();
    state = txState.getText().toString();
    address = etAddress.getText().toString();
    title = txTitle.getText().toString();
    other = txOther.getText().toString();
    size = txSize.getText().toString();
    detail = etDetail.getText().toString();

    Intent i = getIntent();
    property = i.getStringExtra("house_property");
}

public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    txProperty.setText(property);

    houses = db.getInfo(property);

    txType.setText(houses.getTypes());
    txFullname.setText(houses.getFullname());
    txPrice.setText(houses.getPrice());
    txState.setText(houses.getState());
    etAddress.setText(houses.getAddress());
    txTitle.setText(houses.getTitle());
    txOther.setText(houses.getOther());
    txSize.setText(houses.getSize());
    etDetail.setText(houses.getDetail());

    DeleteData();
}
public void DeleteData() {
    bDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SellerHouseDetail.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Delete Record");
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_delete_layout);
            dialog.show();

            Button bYes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bYes);
            Button bNo = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bNo);

            bYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Integer deletedRows = db.deleteData(txProperty.getText().toString());
                    if(deletedRows > 0)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(SellerHouseDetail.this,"House Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(SellerHouseDetail.this,"House not Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            bNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    }
}
```

here is my listview activity that had problem

```
public class SellerHouses extends ListActivity {
TextView house_property;
String fullname;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seller_houses);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    fullname = i.getStringExtra("fullname");
}
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    HousesDB list = new HousesDB(this);
    // list.insertProduct();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> houseList =  list.getSellerHouseList(fullname);
    if(houseList.size()!=0) {
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

                house_property = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shouse_property);
                String houseproperty = house_property.getText().toString();

                //Go to House Detail

                Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SellerHouseDetail.class);
                objIndent.putExtra("house_property",houseproperty);
                startActivity(objIndent);
            }
        });
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( SellerHouses.this,houseList, R.layout.activity_seller_house_info, new String[] { "id","property","type","state"}, new int[] {R.id.shouse_Id, R.id.shouse_property, R.id.shouse_type, R.id.shouse_state});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Houses is found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem lies within this section :

```
if(houseList.size()!=0) {
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

            house_property = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shouse_property);
            String houseproperty = house_property.getText().toString();

            //Go to House Detail

            Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SellerHouseDetail.class);
            objIndent.putExtra("house_property",houseproperty);
            startActivity(objIndent);
        }
    });
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( SellerHouses.this,houseList, R.layout.activity_seller_house_info, new String[] { "id","property","type","state"}, new int[] {R.id.shouse_Id, R.id.shouse_property, R.id.shouse_type, R.id.shouse_state});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}else{
    Toast.makeText(this, "No Houses is found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Do It like this :

```
ListView lv = getListView();
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( SellerHouses.this,houseList, R.layout.activity_seller_house_info, new String[] { "id","property","type","state"}, new int[] {R.id.shouse_Id, R.id.shouse_property, R.id.shouse_type, R.id.shouse_state});
setListAdapter(adapter);

if(houseList.size()!=0) {       
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            house_property = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shouse_property);
            String houseproperty = house_property.getText().toString();

            //Go to House Detail

            Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SellerHouseDetail.class);
            objIndent.putExtra("house_property",houseproperty);
            startActivity(objIndent);
        }
    });

}else{
    Toast.makeText(this, "No Houses is found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And you are fine :),
Though This is not the optimized way to do it but for now it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use `startActivityForResult` method in this kind of situation

```
Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SellerHouseDetail.class);
     objIndent.putExtra("house_property",houseproperty);
            startActivityForResult(objIndent, 1);
```

If you deleted something you can send result as some value as OK from **SellerHouseDetail**

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
 returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
 setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
 finish();
```

If you didn't delete anything then just set `RESULT_CANCELED`

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);        
finish();
```

And In your **SellerHouses**
Override the `onActivityResult()` method

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  if (requestCode == 1) {

 if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
     //Update your listview like
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( SellerHouses.this,houseList, R.layout.activity_seller_house_info, new String[] { "id","property","type","state"}, new int[] {R.id.shouse_Id, R.id.shouse_property, R.id.shouse_type, R.id.shouse_state});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
 }
 if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    
     //You don't need to refresh
  }
 }
}
```

Note : I recommend you to extract your codes to adapt data to your listview in a method as refreshListView like following

```
 public void refreshListView( //Required parameters if necessary) {

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( SellerHouses.this,houseList, R.layout.activity_seller_house_info, new String[] { "id","property","type","state"}, new int[] {R.id.shouse_Id, R.id.shouse_property, R.id.shouse_type, R.id.shouse_state});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

And call this method if you need to refresh your ListView.

Comment: don't you think this solution will again cause a data refreshment problem because you are again using that same ArrayList which has all the records with it like those were never deleted. you need to update your ArrayList accordingly or need to query DB again to fetch updated list.

Comment: @TheVOYOU definitely you have to. You have to query from database again and adapt those to your listview. I haven't seen your code so deeply that how you were retrieving data from database. But what you need to do now is Put your all codes which retrieves data and adapt those to listview in your refreshListView method. And use that method whenever you need to refresh your list. Either after deleting or after inserting new. Hope this may help you.

Comment: @TheVOYOU ohh I'm sorry, I thought that you were asking the question... And It's the way usually most programmers do. your trick is also good +1 for your solution then.

Comment: Thanks Man Cheers :)

Comment: The optimization which I was taking at the end of the answer +1 for the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( SellerHouses.this,houseList, R.layout.activity_seller_house_info, new String[] { "id","property","type","state"}, new int[] {R.id.shouse_Id, R.id.shouse_property, R.id.shouse_type, R.id.shouse_state});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() //refresh listview
```